# Create MP4 video using FFMPEG and JPEG2000 frames

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, grayscale, jpeg2000

I'm trying to create an MP4 video with ffmpeg using JPEG2000 images as frames.

It works when the JPEG2000 is 8bpp, but I need it to work for at least 12 bits (ideally 12, but could be 16). The images are grayscale.

This is the command I'm using:

ffmpeg.exe -i imagen.jp2 video1.mp4

If I try to use -pix_fmt it says it's not supported by the encoder (it doesn't matter which format I use).

Some sample images can be found here:

http://ioingresodemanda.com/jp2.rar

I could also use any other tool, it doesn't need to be ffmpeg.

**UPDATE:** Adding ffmpeg output - http://pastebin.com/NyY3vgpz

Thanks in advance

Comment: Complete ffmpeg console output is missing. Please provide it as it can contains useful information; otherwise guessing is required.

Comment: Done! Updated with the output

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with mp4 file having a different video format the following will work

```
ffmpeg -strict -2 -i 12bit.jp2  -vcodec libx264  -an out.mp4
ffmpeg -strict -2 -i 12bit.jp2  -vcodec mpeg4 -an out.mp4
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response! I tried with those commands but I keep getting "Incompatible pixel format 'gray' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'". Did it work for you? Maybe I have a different version of ffmpeg or some library is missing. Here's an example of the output: http://ioingresodemanda.com/video1.mp4 . It doesn't look so good, but maybe that's because of the player, file size looks good. Is there any command that will let me extract the frames? . I don't care if the video can't be played. I only need it to compare storage potential against Motion JP2. Thanks!

Comment: @user1559108 `-sameq` does not mean "same quality". This is understandable however as the old documentation used to imply this, but it updated a while ago. Also, this option is not designed to be used between formats that do not share the same quantizer scale.

Comment: @Leondro,  I tried wihtout the -sameq option as well. I do get a clean picture in my command. See my complete output from ffmpeg. Perhaps you can compare and find something out. http://pastebin.com/f67HwfDF

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Today I downloaded the latest version I could find from here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ and the output I get is the one I updated in the description. Now I'm getting a broken video that weighs around 2 KB. What I see is that my output has a lot more of configuration options. Can you tell me where did you get the version you're using? Thanks!

Comment: @av501, is it possible that you send me the video generated with your command? I want to check it's properties and compare them to mine and also see if, maybe, it's my computer that can't reproduce it.

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/byyuh1Z8 is the ffmpeg output. I will try and see where I can upload the files. this will give the details of teh format and other things

Comment: I play it using ffplay. See the pastebin link for details of format depth etc.

Comment: One thing you need to do (different from me) is build x264 with bitdepth of 10 for higher bitdepth. However you get the 444P format from ffmpeg / x264 to handle the color format.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg doesn't support 12-bit color. Most of the H264 profiles only support 8-bit color; a few support 10-bit, and only the super-obscure lossless Hi444PP profile supports 14-bit color. The x264 encoder does support some of the profiles with 10-bit color, but that's as far as it goes, and you have to explicitly enable it using the `--bit-depth` option:

http://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=commit;h=d058f37d9af8fc425fa0626695a190eb3aa032af

As noted in the commit, you may also want to keep in mind that "very few H.264 decoders support >8 bit depth currently".

Comment: Hi @duskwuff, is this also true for grayscale?

Comment: Very few encoders support monochrome (4:0:0) formats at all. Only one I'm aware of is Elecard, which is commercial.

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate further with this data.